# How to safely remove a duplicate index from a Rails 3 schema?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, indexing

I'm working on a Rails 3 app, and we recently realized we have a duplicate index:

```
# from schema.rb
add_index "dogs", ["owner_id"], :name => "index_dogs_on_owner"
add_index "dogs", ["owner_id"], :name => "index_dogs_on_owner_id"
```

How can I check which index ActiveRecord is using for relevant queries? Or do I even need to? If one of the indices is removed will ActiveRecord happily just use the other?

I can play around with it locally, but I'm not sure our production environment behaves exactly the same at the DB level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the index is arbitrary. The database engine will look at the indexes based on the column name, not the human name. The index will not affect ActiveRecord. I recommend removing whichever index is least obvious, in this case `index_dogs_on_owner`, because the other index is clearly on the `owner_id` column.

```
remove_index :dogs, :name => 'index_dogs_on_owner'
```

Cite: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_index